# WebView Inside FlipView - Blinking When GotFocus

Tags: windows-8, webview, flipview

I try to make an application to display `WebView` inside a `FlipView`

```
<FlipView Name="mainPage"
    <WebView Name="wv1" Source="http://www.google.com/" 
        Width="1024" Height="768" />
    <WebView Name="wv2" Source="http://www.google.co.id/" 
        Width="1024" Height="768" />
    <WebView Name="wv3" Source="http://www.google.co.uk/" 
        Width="1024" Height="768" />
    <WebView Name="wv4" Source="http://www.google.com.sg/" 
        Width="1024" Height="768" />
</FlipView>
```

The problem is:

- When the `SelectedItem` on `wv2`, and `wv2` `GotFocus` it will display `wv1`, when `wv2` `LostFocus` it will redraw again the `wv2`.
- When the `SelectedItem` on `wv3` or `wv4` and `GotFocus` it will display blank page, when `wv3` or `wv4` `LostFocus` it will redraw again `wv3` or `wv4`.
- When the `SelectedItem` on `wv1` there is no problem when `GotFocus` and there is no blinking.

**Can anyone help me to give a direction what is wrong and maybe the best implementation for `WebView` inside of `FlipView`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer in this [forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1f0a57f2-2534-4aad-96d6-f82701da5890/blinking-when-got-focus-webview-inside-flipview), just add the FlipView.ItemsPanel inside the FlipView and the problem will solve.

```
<FlipView Name="mainPage">
     <FlipView.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </FlipView.ItemsPanel>
     <WebView Name="wv1" Source="http://www.google.com/" Width="1024" Height="768" />
     <WebView Name="wv2" Source="http://www.google.co.id/" Width="1024" Height="768" />
     <WebView Name="wv3" Source="http://www.google.co.uk/" Width="1024" Height="768" />
     <WebView Name="wv4" Source="http://www.google.com.sg/" Width="1024" Height="768" />
 </FlipView>
```